# How do I fix Stack Too Deep Error on Solidity?

Tags: token, solidity, remix

On solidity, I keep getting the 'stack too deep' error. I was wondering if anyone can help me fix this with in following code:

```
function _getTValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 tFee = calculateTaxFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tLiquidity = calculateLiquidityFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tDev = calculateDevFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tBurn = calculateBurnFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tCharity = calculateCharityFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tTransferAmount = tAmount.sub(tFee).sub(tLiquidity);
                tTransferAmount = tTransferAmount.sub(tDev);
                tTransferAmount = tTransferAmount.sub(tCharity);
                tTransferAmount = tTransferAmount.sub(tBurn);

        return (tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tDev, tBurn, tCharity);
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than 16 local variable (iirc) but in this particular case you don't really need them all. Safemoon has a lot of redundant code, especially in the `getValues` and `transfer` functions. I suggest you have a look at the way this is done in `SafeToken` - https://github.com/solidity-guru/safetoken/blob/main/safetoken.sol

The only reason `_getTValues` is calculating all those t values is to subtract them from the `tTransferAmount` ... but you could just use the sum of all fees, e.g.

```
function _getTValues(uint256 tAmount) ... {
    uint256 tFeesSum = calculateSumOfFees(tAmount);
    uint256 tTransferAmount = tAmount - tFeesSum; // no need to use SafeMath in solidity ^0.8
    return tTransferAmount;
}
```